# $\log_3 100 - \log_3 18 - \log_3 50$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \log_3{100} - \log_3{18} - \log_3{50} $$

How do I solve?

Comment: Subtraction is not associative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log_3{\frac{100}{18\cdot 50}}=\log_3{\frac{1}{9}}=-2$$

Comment: Why does the third term go to the bottom. So that I can gain a better understanding?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla $\log_b A - \log_b B = \log_b (A/B)$.

Comment: But why is the term term in the denominator? I like to have a deeper understanding why other then memorizing that it does not go to the numerator as a sum would?

Comment: The rule is that $\log_c a - \log_c b = \log_c (a/b)$. (If you want to understand *why* this is true: 1) great! 2) ask for a proof). Applying this to $\log_d a - \log_d b - \log_d c = (\log_d a - \log_d b) - \log_d c = \log_d (a/b) - \log_d c = \log_d ((a/b)/c) = \log_d (a/(bc))$.

Answer (score 1):

Since they all have the same base ($3$), you can combine them. Remember that when logs are subtracted, you divide:

$$\log_3{100} - \log_3{18} - \log_3{50}$$
$$\log_3{\frac{100}{18}} - \log_3{50}$$
$$\log_3{\frac{\frac{100}{18}}{50}}$$
$$\log_3{\frac1{9}}$$

Remember the definition of logs - this is basically saying: *to what power is 3 equal to $\frac1{9}$*? The answer is **-2** (negative makes it $\frac1{3}$, then the squared is so you get $9$).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$\log_3 100 - \log_3 18 - \log_3 50 = \log_3 \left(\frac{100}{18}\right) - \log_3 50 = \log_3 \left(\frac{100/18}{50}\right) = \log_3 \frac{1}{9} = -2.$$